# Embeded youtube video error

Tags: html, video, youtube, embed

I'm trying to embed a youtube video on my site and no matter what video I embed it just says "an error has occurred." (This is the clearly explained problem)

I would like for the video to work. (This is the desired outcome)

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=039nv45oth8"></iframe>
```

(The above is the minimum needed code)

Comment: This also happened to me while using a link with time 't' parameter at the end "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vCe2gbWUnBQ&t=1s". I removed the '&t=1s' and it worked !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/039nv45oth8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: That did it. Is it the border that does it?

Comment: @ActuallyHelpsPeople : Your embed link `https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=039nv45oth8` was wrong.

Comment: Yes, That's correct. If it worked, would you mind marking my post as answered? :)

Comment: I certainly will. As soon as the timer allows me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't have to write your code by yourself,  just go to the video you want to add it in YouTube,  then click the button "SHARE" , select "Embed" and you see the code is ready. Just copy it by clicking "COPY" then paste it in your html code.